# What is the difference between createImageView and createView (Titanium Studio)

Tags: titanium-mobile

I am using Titanium Studio for mobile development.
The following two things used to display image. But may i know the difference between following,

```
1. Ti.UI.createImageView({ width:100, height:50, Image:'image path' });

2. Ti.UI.createView({ width:100, height:50, backgroundImage:'image path' });
```

Both displaying specified image. 
what is the difference between these two. 
craeteView also displaying image then , why we use createImageView.

can any one please..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

View is an empty drawing surface or container, which is the base type for all UI widgets in Titanium where as image view is a view used to display a single image or series of animated images. All events of Titanium.UI.ImageView is Inherited from Titanium.UI.View. You can not make an animation using view and also an image view has some additional events like start, stop, pause, load etc.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is you can show URL image (or Remote image) in ImageView, while you can only show resource image in View

```
var view = Ti.UI.createView();
var imageView = Ti.UI.createImageView();

//Valid:
view.backgroundImage = 'image.png';
imageView.backgroundImage = 'image.png';
imageView.image = 'http://somesite.com/image.png';

//Invalid:
view.backgroundImage = 'http://somesite.com/image.png';
imageView.backgroundImage = 'http://somesite.com/image.png';
```

Also, as @Anand said, you can show series of images in ImageView